# ValueError: decay is deprecated in the new Keras optimizer, or use the legacy optimizer, e.g., tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.SGD

Tags: keras, tensor

I am getting this issue, I did try downgrading Keras as mentioned in other forum but does not work

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0]),), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
 
hist = model.fit(np.array(train_x), np.array(train_y), epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
model.save('chatbot_model.h5', hist)
print("model created")
```